# Ordering a SELECT - Logical issue (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

I'm stuck in this logical issue and I don't know how to proceed.

I have two columns: ID and FOLDERID. As a folder can be subfolder too, I want to order my result by first selecting the folders that has no folderid (root folder), and then their subfolders and on. So this way I will not have any problem like "folder **X** doesn't exists".

In this example, I can´t get what I need by simple ordering by FOLDERID ASC and/or ID ASC.

[image]

The correct result is the 3rd one:

1. First, I get the ID 2 "Teste" folder because it has folderid 0 = root one.
2. Now I want "Controladoria" folder, because the folderid is 2, so it needs the folder ID 2 to be created first (Teste)
3. "PCP" folder, that needs folder with id 1 (Controladoria)
4. "Pasta1" folder, that needs folder with id 3 (PCP)
5. On and On...

I've tried several ways with multiple ORDER BY and JOIN/LEFT JOIN in the same table but can´t figure out how I can do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't explicitly specify an `ORDER BY`, then the ordering is ***undefined*** - there ***is NO implicit*** ordering (e.g. by creation date or anything like that ) in a SQL table

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to order your folders like in a tree (depth-first search)? If so, this involves recursion, and that's nothing SQL is pretty good for.

Comment: @marc_s, by "creation date" I mean the order the registry was written in the table, sorry.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm using SQL SERVER.

Comment: @contradictioned Yeah this is what I want.

Comment: Again: ***there is NO inherent order*** - neither by creation date, nor by the order in which the data was written into the table. Unless you **specify an explicit `ORDER BY`**, there **IS NO ORDER**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple recursive query you can get these results.

```
;WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                1 RN 
         FROM   TABLE1 
         WHERE  FOLDERID = 0 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT T1.*, 
                T2.RN + 1 
         FROM   TABLE1 T1 
                INNER JOIN CTE T2 
                        ON T1.FOLDERID = T2.ID) 
SELECT [ID], 
       [NAME], 
       [FOLDERID] 
FROM   CTE 
ORDER  BY RN
```

Using this query you can also deal with multiple subfolders.

Take a look at the working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40816/10).
If you want a good explenation about recursive queries, take a look at [this blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` statements to `ORDER`, for your example this would work, but it sounds like you might be after a recursive heirarchy, for which the syntax will vary by RDBMS:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN FolderID = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ID
```

Comment: Didn´t know that we can use CASE in ORDER BY. I am using a compact version of SQL SERVER and I think it worked. Thanks!

But I need to ask if you can please explain me what the order by is doing in this code. When we use ORDER BY 0, ORDER BY 1, doesn't it orders by column index? Or the result of case statement is working with another approach that I dont know?

Comment: The output of the case statement above are numeric values 0 and 1 for each row, if you said `ORDER BY 1` you'd be using the column index.  Think of it like this, if you put the `CASE` statement in your `SELECT` you'd get a value for each row, then you could order by that value. Putting it just in the `ORDER` by just spares you from returning the output of it.

Comment: This won't work correctly when subfolder ID is bigger than it's parent ID.

Comment: Very true, it worked for the sample data but it seemed likely that you would ultimately need a recursive approach or similar.

Answer (score 2):

you may opt for a hierarchical query, if your dbms does support this. in oracle syntax:

```
    select id
         , name
         , folderid
         , sys_connect_by_path ( name, '/' )    path
      from table t
connect by prior id = folderid
start with folderid = 0
  order by path
         ;
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. I am using SQL SERVER and found something equivalent to Oracle's CONNECT BY. This fits what I need :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on *collapsar* response, I found a Oracle's CONNECT BY equivalent that solved my issue.

```
WITH n([ID], [NAME], [OWNER], [FOLDERID]) AS 
   (SELECT [ID], [NAME], [OWNER], [FOLDERID]
    FROM [RM_REPORTS_FOLDERS]
    WHERE [FOLDERID] = 0
        UNION ALL
    SELECT nplus1.[ID], nplus1.[NAME], nplus1.[OWNER], nplus1.[FOLDERID] 
    FROM [RM_REPORTS_FOLDERS] as nplus1, n
    WHERE n.[ID] = nplus1.[FOLDERID])
SELECT [ID], [NAME], [OWNER], [FOLDERID] FROM n
```

Comment: There's no guarantee of order with that query.  What works in testing may not work in production.

Comment: Add a depth incrementer to the cte and use that for ordering

Comment: You mean like Gidil response? I'll try to.